# Slidable layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to create a view that can detect sliding motion from users.

It is something like a toggle.

There are two status : On and Off status.

On status witch is having two buttons is able to click.

Off status seems like simple linearlayout with imageView and textView. also that can return On status by sliding opposite.

please look images.

[image]

I appreciate Any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: is your problem solved ? @bubu uwu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this project can help you.
[AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

Comment: too fit! i need this! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a job for ViewDragHelper with setEdgeTrackingEnabled set to true.
Check [my blogpost here](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/dragging-with-viewdraghelper/) and [Flavien Laurent post here](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/)

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to achieve this type of layout than follow this library**

[MaterialLeanBack on GIT](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialLeanBack) checkout this

[image]

> compile 'com.github.florent37:materialleanback:1.0.0@aar'
>
> compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1' compile
>
> 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1' compile
>
> 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

Comment: this was good library, but i really want to create view, like a toggle button, not like gallery.